# Custom Button Changing Value on Originating Record

Tags: custom-button, opportunity, contact

I've built the below-code for a URL Opportunity Custom Button to parameterize the Opportunity with Contact-based data. What I'd like to do here is to, upon clicking, change a Contact field. (This button exists on the Opportunity Related List on Contacts)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity
&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3Flookupcmpgn%3D1%26
&retURL={!Contact.Id}
&accid={!Account.Id}
&opp6={!Contact.LeadSource}
&00Na0000009zQCa={!Contact.Lead_Source_sub_category__c}
&00N1400000B8b6h={!Contact.Lead_Source_Note__c}
&{!Opportunity.OwnerId}={!User.Id}
&conid={!Contact.Id}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are even trying to update the contact record. Button needs to be on click JavaScript and u will need to write the code to do it

Comment: I did not include the Contact record line, as I do not know what to put other than using the Contact merge field, which would not update, as I had tried already. Are you saying that I cannot use a URL type button to accomplish both "destination" object and "origin" object field updates?